# How to change wordpress post content before generate

Tags: wordpress, facebook-webhooks

My post has content:

```
<p>download <a href="https://www.google.com/file/JRWZZPB5HS69" target="_blank">Download</a></p>
<p>download mirror <a href="https://mega.nz/#!Z3wkgaba!KdgfdsDgSDgSDgdsg" target="_blank">Download</a></p>
```

And i have a script to add prefix domain, i put it before `</body>`:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var tui_url = 'https://mydomainasd.com';
        var tui_domains = ['mediafire.com', 'www.abc.com','mega.nz', 'drive.google.com','secufiles.com'];
</script>
<script>
function tui_get_url(e) {
var n = document.createElement("a");
return n.href = e, n
}

function tui_get_host_name(e) {
var n;
return void 0 === e || null === e || "" === e || e.match(/^\#/) ? "" : -1 === (e = tui_get_url(e)).href.search(/^http[s]?:\/\//) ? "" : (n = e.href.split("/")[2], (n = n.split(":")[0]).toLowerCase())
}
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(e) {
if ("undefined" != typeof tui_url) {

    var l = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    if ("undefined" == typeof tui_domains)
        if ("undefined" == typeof tui_exclude_domains);
        else
            for (o = 0; o < l.length; o++) {
                var t = tui_get_host_name(l[o].getAttribute("href"));
                t.length > 0 && -1 === tui_exclude_domains.indexOf(t) ? 
l[o].href = tui_url + "?u=" + encodeURIComponent(l[o].href) : "magnet:" === 
l[o].protocol && (l[o].href = tui_url + "?u=" + encodeURIComponent(l[o].href))
            } else
                for (var o = 0; o < l.length; o++)(t = 
tui_get_host_name(l[o].getAttribute("href"))).length > 0 && 
tui_domains.indexOf(t) > -1 ? l[o].href = tui_url + "?u=" + 
encodeURIComponent(l[o].href): "magnet:" === l[o].protocol && (l[o].href = 
tui_url + "?u=" + encodeURIComponent(l[o].href))
}
});
</script>
```

It works well.

But now I want to it perform this task before generating post content, mean that above script will not appear in output HTML.

I think about creating a plugin or function but I don't know how to do.

Can you help me solve this? sorry for my English

Answer (score 1):

You can try this filter : https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/the_content

You will get the content of the post in your function so you can edit it with PHP before display it.

You can put this code in functions.php at the root of your theme or in a plugin.